# load colon separated values into a dbms_sql.varchar2_table

Tags: arrays, plsql

I have a variable, **l_addr_list** that contains a list of colon-separated values.  I'd like to load each value in that list into an individual row in a dbms_sql.varchar2_table but I don't know how to do it.  Here's code that illustrates the request:

```
Declare
    l_addr_list     varchar2(1024);
    l_addresses     dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
Begin
    l_addr_list := '12:14:16:25:52';
    -- I'd like to load the colon-separated values from l_addr_list into
    -- the l_addresses table but don't know how.

    For i IN l_addresses.FIRST .. l_addresses.LAST
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('The current value is ' || l_addresses(i) );
    end loop;
End;
```

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: If you are looking for a split() function, you'll have to write one. There are various SQL solutions, mostly hacking `connect by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `dbms_sql.varchar2_table` is an associative array. The elements can be assigned one by one (not that fast).

```
DECLARE
    l_addr_list     varchar2(1024);
    l_addr_list_vct dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
BEGIN
    l_addr_list := '12:14:16:25:52';

    FOR i IN 
    (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_addr_list, '[^:]+', 1, rownum) split, rownum rn
      FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (regexp_replace (l_addr_list, '[^:]+'))  + 1)    
    
    LOOP
      l_addr_list_vct(i.rn) := i.split;
    END LOOP;
    
    FOR r IN 1 .. l_addr_list_vct.COUNT LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('value is '||l_addr_list_vct(r));
    END LOOP;
END;
/

value is 12
value is 14
value is 16
value is 25
value is 52


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

or be populated using `BULK COLLECT`

```
DECLARE
    l_addr_list     varchar2(1024);
    l_addr_list_vct dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
BEGIN
    l_addr_list := '12:14:16:25:52';

    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (l_addr_list, '[^:]+', 1, rownum)
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_addr_list_vct
      FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (regexp_replace (l_addr_list, '[^:]+'))  + 1    ;
    
    
    FOR r IN 1 .. l_addr_list_vct.COUNT LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('value is '||l_addr_list_vct(r));
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

OR... if you have Oracle APEX installed in your database (that is a no-cost option) take advantage of the `APEX_STRING` API.

```
DECLARE
    l_addr_list     varchar2(1024);
    l_addr_list_vct dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
BEGIN
    l_addr_list := '12:14:16:25:52';

    SELECT column_value 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_addr_list_vct
      FROM apex_string.split_numbers(l_addr_list,':');
    
    
    FOR r IN 1 .. l_addr_list_vct.COUNT LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('value is '||l_addr_list_vct(r));
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help Keon.  All work perfectly.  As it happens, I have APEX installed so the last solution works perfectly.  I really appreciate it!